# Problems with date column and geom_ribbon in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Follow up question to a previously asked one ([Plotting depth range in 'time-series' using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14704909/2017461)), but sort of the exact same thing.

Using ggplot I want a plot to show how a specific individual (eg 7303, see code sample below) depth range variates around a mean (min and max) for a 3mnd period using `geom_ribbon()`.

Varibles in the dataset;

```
names(df)
[1] "ID"    "MONTH" "DAY"   "MIN"   "MEAN"  "MAX"   "date"
```

How I chose a single individual:

```
df<-Dybde_dag_gjsn[which(Dybde_dag_gjsn$ID=="7303"),]
```

I tried the following;

```
ggplot(data=df)+
    geom_line(aes(x=date,y=-MEAN,group=ID,colour=as.factor(ID))) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x=date,ymin=-MIN,ymax=-MAX,group=ID),fill="grey") +
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

But the outcome was less than satisfying, showing only 'vertical means' and not the ones in between:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/85946387/fail_7303.jpeg]

I am thinking it has something to do with my `grouping factor` (ref: the book "ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis (Use R!)" *bottom of p.50*). I used ID as grouping factor for a diff plot where I had numerous individuals in the same plot, but of course that didn't work here seeing I only have **ONE** ID now.

How do I solve this?!
I've been reading and reading up on ggplot but all in vain..

Heres the code sample for it:

```
 > dput(df)
    structure(list(ID = c(7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 
    7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L, 7303L), MONTH = c(6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 10L), DAY = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), MIN = c(11.802917, 
    8.604167, 14.318936, 14.836458, 10.16625, 8.58093, 12.620833, 
    11.216667, 9.742083, 16.554167, 14.662708, 11.58375, 8.401957, 
    17.662553, 11.33413, 8.3275, 16.664167, 13.108, 12.163542, 8.024783, 
    16.394255, 12.450625, 7.730208, 17.397083, 14.680833, 12.08875, 
    8.810435, 15.019792, 10.742292, 11.911489, 17.621111, 14.555319, 
    11.092292, 10.339583, 15.487083, 9.9375, 12.747708, 16.411458, 
    13.903542, 10.94875, 10.164375, 16.915625, 7.065417, 12.83375, 
    18.342979, 13.549167, 11.229792, 10.56875, 18.430444, 6.761042, 
    12.088723, 18.041489, 12.976458, 10.995625, 9.83, 17.677083, 
    9.044737, 8.485208, 8.480833, 18.887609, 13.97125, 10.979583, 
    9.73, 12.843913, 12.495833, 9.311042, 11.773958, 17.697447, 12.004583, 
    9.507083, 8.385417, 16.856596, 13.131458, 8.656458, 10.16625, 
    17.634255, 14.123542, 9.138958, 9.999583, 18.634043, 12.649583, 
    8.672917, 13.166458, 17.596222, 13.121875, 8.397708, 10.421667, 
    20.087805, 14.496042, 10.430833, 10.553333, 17.742979, 12.378125, 
    8.736458, 8.713125, 19.968421, 13.571875, 11.819792, 8.847021, 
    18.748085, 14.197917, 8.918125, 9.3475, 11.85625, 11.089583, 
    13.461458, 18.761277, 11.001702, 8.621458, 9.194375, 11.738333, 
    12.283404, 15.249583, 17.522609, 11.655625, 8.725957, 9.024792, 
    12.361875, 12.311702, 11.959167, 16.179333, 11.733542, 11.0825, 
    11.635208, 12.139792, 10.24875, 11.147917, 15.690851, 11.7175, 
    8.537708, 8.896458, 11.342917, 9.42875, 12.289167, 13.904894, 
    13.622766, 9.262292, 10.925417, 12.507917, 9.640417, 11.619167, 
    13.693333, 12.81375, 8.737021, 8.725217, 12.851042, 9.978958, 
    11.987917, 12.68875, 13.178125, 8.613125, 8.759574, 13.125833, 
    12.803191, 10.768085, 14.104583, 12.426042, 8.590208, 10.004792, 
    11.335417, 10.126458, 11.02, 13.675625, 12.153333, 8.786667, 
    8.901522, 10.190208, 9.675417, 12.787708, 12.376875, 12.686596, 
    9.266042, 9.486875, 11.187083, 11.984583, 14.908125, 12.341042, 
    8.603617, 8.950417, 9.289574, 12.193125, 11.034583, 14.760417, 
    14.270417, 10.900426, 9.456667, 9.817333, 11.300625, 9.979362, 
    18.275532, 14.270833, 10.328333, 8.991667, 9.73234, 10.31625, 
    12.294167, 17.291875, 14.166889, 10.655625, 9.542917, 9.423542, 
    13.408542, 11.412708, 15.77875, 13.872174, 10.414583, 8.771458, 
    10.196667, 13.245957, 9.7525, 14.025625, 14.0225, 10.283333, 
    10.124375, 11.077708, 11.284375, 12.960625, 13.672917, 8.689535
    ), MEAN = c(12.770743, 10.404807, 15.731308, 15.718022, 11.039786, 
    9.592478, 13.566293, 11.997254, 11.060343, 17.321561, 15.434626, 
    12.521116, 9.173196, 20.231528, 12.183485, 9.494385, 17.661506, 
    13.833904, 13.130883, 9.006861, 17.73971, 13.204396, 8.896995, 
    18.11753, 15.600875, 13.121007, 10.101822, 16.769785, 11.697461, 
    12.764369, 18.282592, 15.310545, 12.133705, 11.40675, 16.982279, 
    11.110351, 13.55874, 17.101128, 14.624049, 11.851105, 11.142173, 
    18.371564, 8.477442, 13.410731, 18.981083, 14.22986, 12.254827, 
    11.94385, 19.470508, 8.074123, 12.675037, 18.886745, 13.915082, 
    12.136526, 11.31768, 18.839881, 10.007904, 9.772924, 9.81347, 
    19.389361, 14.811928, 12.119235, 10.951059, 14.149285, 13.293671, 
    10.514356, 12.565706, 18.040379, 12.948702, 10.605055, 9.573924, 
    18.062445, 14.017553, 9.602413, 11.364352, 18.259258, 15.170781, 
    9.967036, 11.390614, 19.553701, 13.97901, 9.462041, 13.8245, 
    18.099865, 14.177431, 9.98118, 11.685662, 20.804762, 15.019522, 
    11.354073, 11.534092, 18.394013, 13.326405, 9.616245, 9.949249, 
    20.426667, 14.46714, 12.737376, 9.717531, 19.227388, 15.078364, 
    9.844263, 10.303065, 12.92404, 12.265582, 14.105216, 19.288396, 
    12.052717, 9.491347, 10.529289, 13.096898, 13.369252, 16.28977, 
    18.160727, 12.549057, 9.604447, 10.280789, 13.554763, 13.393719, 
    12.50955, 16.820558, 12.850228, 12.094866, 12.630164, 13.385122, 
    11.273304, 11.961472, 16.330921, 12.611663, 9.617874, 10.167019, 
    12.655299, 10.373309, 13.374857, 14.925013, 14.537989, 10.447603, 
    12.508138, 13.349818, 10.680128, 12.326957, 15.049259, 13.660166, 
    9.696145, 9.914241, 13.980217, 10.761571, 12.556846, 13.99646, 
    14.085468, 9.438403, 9.728357, 14.105513, 13.989112, 11.698711, 
    14.95036, 13.363272, 9.401711, 10.865912, 12.682327, 11.131757, 
    11.846839, 14.42893, 13.07079, 9.819241, 9.933585, 11.365231, 
    10.918715, 14.062566, 13.084255, 13.71815, 10.182433, 10.690687, 
    12.208993, 13.50174, 15.4533, 13.201188, 9.811705, 9.881868, 
    10.245386, 12.971602, 11.964325, 15.679961, 15.016042, 11.940247, 
    10.361256, 10.998961, 12.15253, 11.044938, 19.022599, 14.954921, 
    11.48031, 10.01924, 10.652463, 11.569661, 13.298019, 17.929547, 
    15.186122, 11.539514, 10.618905, 10.354405, 14.389687, 12.624194, 
    16.338045, 14.791213, 11.211347, 9.772962, 12.016292, 14.260883, 
    10.820083, 14.909629, 14.889066, 11.19011, 11.194178, 12.819223, 
    12.179042, 14.309247, 14.722921, 9.69601), MAX = c(13.891875, 
    12.046875, 16.884468, 16.663333, 12.111875, 10.590465, 14.557708, 
    12.835833, 12.286458, 18.15125, 16.4475, 13.609167, 9.929783, 
    22.586596, 13.212826, 10.684792, 18.319792, 14.831333, 14.148958, 
    10.042826, 19.206383, 14.106667, 9.974375, 18.710625, 16.462917, 
    14.298958, 11.42913, 18.739583, 12.672708, 13.598723, 18.842222, 
    16.099149, 13.169167, 12.736458, 18.593125, 12.367708, 14.195833, 
    17.82625, 15.53375, 12.754375, 12.278125, 20.19, 9.94375, 13.917292, 
    19.738511, 14.916458, 13.339375, 13.453542, 20.28, 9.341042, 
    13.397234, 19.54, 14.982083, 13.249792, 12.602083, 20.058333, 
    10.945789, 11.00875, 10.901875, 19.990217, 15.745, 13.379583, 
    12.361042, 15.389565, 14.012917, 11.743958, 13.204167, 18.383404, 
    13.976667, 11.698958, 10.67125, 19.185106, 14.927083, 10.43, 
    12.549167, 18.929149, 16.060833, 10.792708, 12.95, 20.521277, 
    15.096667, 10.184792, 14.455208, 18.589778, 15.085208, 11.300208, 
    13.256875, 21.602439, 15.5625, 12.430625, 12.52375, 18.934043, 
    14.175417, 10.624792, 11.299583, 20.831579, 15.508333, 13.814792, 
    10.412766, 19.688511, 15.974583, 10.839583, 11.752083, 14.33625, 
    13.332708, 14.671667, 19.667447, 12.983404, 10.354583, 11.980833, 
    14.325833, 14.310426, 17.290833, 18.684783, 13.448958, 10.530851, 
    11.582708, 14.854375, 14.357234, 13.0875, 17.491111, 14.056458, 
    12.958125, 13.423333, 14.718542, 12.291458, 12.82125, 16.907872, 
    13.553125, 11.034375, 11.5625, 13.86375, 11.493542, 14.3025, 
    15.835957, 15.34383, 11.731667, 14.293125, 14.225625, 11.83875, 
    12.958125, 16.238333, 14.615625, 10.958085, 11.225435, 14.90375, 
    11.537083, 13.103958, 15.006458, 14.866458, 10.4675, 10.701702, 
    15.096875, 15.155319, 12.481702, 15.745208, 14.3425, 10.37875, 
    11.7625, 13.89875, 12.302708, 12.761875, 15.10625, 14.171875, 
    10.985625, 10.838696, 12.592708, 12.229167, 15.030833, 13.759792, 
    14.696809, 11.215, 12.2125, 13.277292, 14.844375, 15.933542, 
    13.974583, 11.086809, 10.918542, 11.214894, 13.733542, 12.78375, 
    16.320625, 15.781667, 12.809362, 11.3175, 12.139778, 13.163958, 
    11.853617, 19.77383, 15.644375, 12.645625, 11.055417, 11.401702, 
    12.80125, 14.210625, 18.491667, 15.958444, 12.377083, 11.693333, 
    11.346667, 15.291458, 13.693542, 16.73125, 15.604565, 12.090833, 
    10.700417, 13.640208, 15.333404, 11.697292, 15.565, 15.66375, 
    12.119583, 12.334167, 14.415833, 13.394792, 15.494583, 15.681042, 
    10.907907), date = structure(c(15522, 15553, 15492, 15522, 15553, 
    15492, 15522, 15554, 15493, 15523, 15554, 15493, 15523, 15554, 
    15494, 15524, 15555, 15494, 15524, 15555, 15494, 15525, 15556, 
    15495, 15525, 15556, 15495, 15525, 15557, 15496, 15526, 15557, 
    15496, 15526, 15557, 15497, 15527, 15558, 15497, 15527, 15558, 
    15497, 15528, 15559, 15498, 15528, 15559, 15498, 15528, 15560, 
    15499, 15529, 15560, NA, 15499, 15499, 15500, 15500, 15500, 15530, 
    15500, 15500, 15500, 15561, 15501, 15531, 15501, 15501, 15531, 
    15501, 15531, 15562, 15532, 15502, 15532, 15502, 15532, 15532, 
    15502, 15532, 15533, 15564, 15533, 15564, 15564, 15564, 15564, 
    15564, 15565, 15565, 15565, 15565, 15534, 15534, 15534, 15504, 
    15505, 15505, 15535, 15505, 15535, 15505, 15505, 15536, 15506, 
    15506, 15536, 15506, 15506, 15506, 15537, 15507, 15568, 15568, 
    15568, 15568, 15568, 15569, 15569, 15569, 15569, 15569, 15569, 
    15569, 15570, 15570, 15570, 15570, 15570, 15539, 15570, 15571, 
    15540, 15571, 15540, 15540, 15571, 15540, 15572, 15541, 15511, 
    15541, 15511, 15541, 15541, 15542, 15512, 15512, 15512, 15573, 
    15512, 15512, 15513, 15513, 15513, 15574, 15513, 15543, 15574, 
    15514, 15544, 15514, 15514, 15514, 15514, 15575, 15545, 15576, 
    15515, 15545, 15515, 15576, 15576, 15546, 15577, 15546, 15516, 
    15546, 15577, 15546, 15578, 15517, 15517, 15547, 15578, 15547, 
    15547, 15579, 15518, 15579, 15518, 15579, 15548, 15548, 15580, 
    15580, 15519, 15549, 15519, 15549, 15519, 15520, 15520, 15581, 
    15550, 15581, 15550, 15520, 15521, 15551, 15582, 15582, 15582, 
    15521, 15551, 15583, 15552, 15583, 15583), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "MONTH", "DAY", "MIN", "MEAN", "MAX", "date"), row.names = 1128:1346, class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate all pointers coming my way! Cheers

**UPDATE: Problem resolved, and everything worked out splendidly;**

[image]

Comment: (+1) for a nice post. It'd be much nicer if you edit your title explaining the issue in the title instead of "ggplot2 ribbon issues".

Comment: Sorry, but what's wrong with the plot? Could you clarify? Or what does "less than satisfying" mean?

Comment: Switch the `geom_ribbon` and `geom_line` lines.

Comment: I suspect, there is something wrong with your date. The month of the date is not identical to the MONTH column, which results in some dates being not unique.

Comment: I concur, the dataset does look fishy. I tried out using only August here; http://dl.dropbox.com/u/85946387/fail_7303_aug.jpeg . What I'm wondering is why is it not a 'smooth mean' output, it has so many vertical lines if you know.. But I suppose its a strange dataset I have on my hands, and not really a faulty method.

Comment: You can try to recreate the dates: `df$date2 <- as.Date(paste("2012",df$MONTH,df$DAY,sep="-"),"%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: Thanks guys - Yeah, the dataset def did not include enough information hence its all .. "staggered" and weird. My bad for not thinking of it, it DID help with switching the lines for ribbon and line and thats as good as it gets I suppose. :)

Comment: @IdaFish, you *really* have to read through the comments.

Comment: @Arun I know, I have and I tried out the suggestions and found out (humbly) that I made the error of thinking there was something wrong method-wise, when actually my dataset is whats causing the error.

Comment: @IdaFish, I was talking about editing your title *and* clarifying what *less than satisfying* mean (by editing your original post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that the dates are not unique, which results in those vertical lines. Since the months of the `date` column are not identical with the `MONTH` column, there seems to be something wrong with the data. Furthermore, you need to switch the order of `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon`, to have the lines drawn on top.

You can recreate the dates as follows:

```
df$date2 <- as.Date(paste("2012",df$MONTH,df$DAY,sep="-"),"%Y-%m-%d")

ggplot(data=df)+  
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=date2,ymin=-MIN,ymax=-MAX),fill="grey") +
  geom_line(aes(x=date2,y=-MEAN)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, but what if I now only want months 6 thru 8 (aka june-aug) ? Will `df$date2 <- as.Date(paste("2012",df$MONTH[df$MONTH==6:8],df$DAY,sep="-"),"%Y-%m-%d")` produce what I wish? Cause I tried it and I'm not certain if I got it right this time either

Comment: subset the data.frame after recreating the dates, e.g., `df[df$MONTH %in% 6:8,]`.