# plotting average with confidence interval in ggplot2 for time-series data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, confidence-interval

From the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph), we create some dummy data. Then it is converted into a format which `ggplot2` can understand, and we generate a simple graph showing changes in `var` over time.

```
test_data <-
  data.frame(
    var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
    var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    var2 = 120 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -5, 10))),
    date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100)
  )
#
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
#
test_data_long <- melt(test_data, id="date")  # convert to long format

ggplot(data=test_data_long,
       aes(x=date, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

I want to plot the average of the three `var` in the same graph, and show a confidence interval for the average. *possibly with +-1SD*. For this I think the `stat_summary()` function can be used, as was outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341056/plotting-average-of-multiple-variables-in-time-series-using-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633714/adding-a-regression-line-on-a-ggplot/15654715#15654715).

By adding either of the commands below, I do not obtain the average, nor a confidence interval. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal)
  #stat_summary(fun.data ="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom = "smooth")
  #stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "smooth")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood correctly you wanna display average of all three parameters (var0,var1 and var3) with standard deviation.

I do have for you two solutions. First one imply `dplyr` package and calculation of the **standard deviation and average row-wise** and further display using `geom_ribbon()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
q <- test_data
q <- q %>% rowwise() %>% transmute(date, mean=mean(c(var0,var1,var2), na.rm=TRUE), sd = sd(c(var0,var1,var2), na.rm=TRUE))

eb <- aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd)
ggplot(data = q, aes(x = date, y = mean)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2) + 
  geom_ribbon(eb, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Second solution imply mentioned by you `stat_summary()`, which actually works well with the code you have provided:

```
ggplot(data=test_data_long, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data ="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom = "smooth") + theme_bw()
```

[image]